# Setting Android SeekBar position to finger position on initial touch

Tags: android, seekbar

I have a seekbar and I would like to set the position (progress) to the match the position of your finger when you first touch it... I want you to be able to touch it and have it snap to where you touched it immediately, and then function normally allowing you to drag it until you remove your finger.

I know I will have to do this in the onStartTrackingTouch() function and I will have to call seekBar.setProgress() but I'm not sure how to get the seekBar progress equivalent of the location of your touch.

Thank you.

Comment: If this isnt resolved by tonight, when i get home, ill look through my code.  The way i have deals with multiple concatenated audio files, but on the base with the finger touching is easy.  Did you add the approperiate touch listener to the item?  see if that works?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working solution :

```
private void onStartTrackingTouch(MotionEvent event) {
    firstTouchAngle = TouchAngle;
}


private void onUpdateTouch(MotionEvent event) {
    newTouchAngle = TouchAngle;
    if (Math.abs(newTouchAngle - firstTouchAngle) > 3) {
        //do something
    }
}
```